Вернуть одним списком значения из разных столбцов таблицы
У меня есть таблица заказов, в которой указаны составляющие заказа:
create table order
(
    goods_id bigint,
    dish_id bigint,
    combo_id bigint
)

Мне надо получить все такие айдишники из заказа в виде списка. Можно ли сделать это одним запросом? Каким образом?
То есть если в таблице заказов есть запись
goods_id    dish_id    combo_id
123          456        789

то надо вернуть
result
123
456
789

Например так.

Крайне плохая структура. Лучше хранить в EAV - вот то, что получаешь, просто с пометкой категории значения.

Но зачем? Чем вас не устраивает "горизонтальный" список?
select goods_id, dish_id, combo_id from order

А так то можно и "вертикальный" сделать, конечно:
select goods_id as result from order
union all
select dish_id as result from order
union all
select combo_id as result from order

